# Eliminar objeto de una arraylist y añadirlo a otra arraylist comprobando si el objeto ya ha salido antes

Tags: java, arraylist

En este ejercicio necesito realizar el case 1: que consiste en sacar una bola del bingo. La arraylist bolas ya tiene sus 30 bolas con su color, necesito añadir una bola random a la arraylist sacadas y eliminar la bola que ha salido de la arraylist bolas

Clase Bola:

```
public class Bola {
    
Integer numero;
String color;

public Bola(Integer numero){
    this.numero = numero;
    this.setcolor(numero);
}

public Integer getNumero(){
    return this.numero;
}

public void setcolor(Integer numero){
    if (numero%2 == 0) {
        this.color = "B";
    }else{
        this.color = "N";
    }
}

public String getColor(){
    return this.color;
}
```

}

Case 1 donde tengo el fallo:

```
case 1:
              
  random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,30+1);

  for (Bola bola : bolas) {
     if (bola.getNumero().equals(random)) {
        System.out.println("Ha salido la bola: " + bola.getNumero()+bola.getColor());
        sacadas.add(bola);
        bolas.remove(bola);
     }else{
        System.out.println("La bola ya ha salido");
     }
  }
  break;
```

Error:

Necesito conseguir eliminar la bola que tiene el numero random

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que el forEach usa un Iterator internamente para atravesar elementos en a Collection, ejecutar el código anterior provoca un ConcurrentModificationException ya que se usa el remove()método de Collection en lugar del iterador [Fuente](https://rollbar.com/blog/java-concurrentmodificationexception/)

Solución usar el bucle for tradicional para iterar y asi mismo poder usar remove

```
for (int i=0;i<bolas.size();i++) {
     if (bolas.get(i).getNumero()==random) {
        System.out.println("Ha salido la bola: " + bolas.get(i).getNumero()+bolas.get(i).getColor());
        sacadas.add(bolas.get(i));
        bolas.remove(bolas.get(i));
     }else{
        System.out.println("La bola ya ha salido");
     }
  }
```